# Create a new model in View.event Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, model, frontend

Let's say I'm building a simple app, that allows me to add Movies and display them in a list. Here's my code (body):

```
<div id="container-addmovie"></div>
<p>Movies:</p>
<ul id="container-movie"></ul>

<!-- templates  -->
<!-- Movie template -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-movie">
    <li><strong>Title: </strong><%=title%>; <strong>Rating: </strong><%=mpaaRating%></li>
</script> 
<!-- add movie template -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-addmovie">
    <input type="text" name="" id="input-addmovie">
    <input type="button" name="" id="button-addmovie" value="Add new movie">
</script> 

<!-- models -->
<!-- movie model -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});
</script>

<!-- views -->
<!-- movie view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#container-movie",
        template: _.template($("#template-movie").html()),
        initialize: function() {
            // model reder
            this.render();
            // change event
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            console.log("MovieView render; Movie Title: " + this.model.get("title"));
            var htmlOutput = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(htmlOutput);
            return this;
        }
    })
</script>
<!-- add movie view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AddMovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // model reder
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            var template =  _.template($("#template-addmovie").html());
            this.$el.html ( template );
        },
        events: {
            "click input[type=button]": "addNewMovie"
        },
        addNewMovie: function (event) {
            var movieModel = new Movie({ title: $("#input-addmovie").val(), mpaaRating: "R" });
            var movieView = new MovieView({ model: movieModel });   
        }
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var addMovie = new AddMovieView( {el: $("#container-addmovie")} )
</script>
```

The problem is when I'm initiating `addNewMovie` event...

```
var movieModel = new Movie({ title: $("#input-addmovie").val(), mpaaRating: "R" });
var movieView = new MovieView({ model: movieModel });
```

...I'm not creating a new model, but overwriting exiting. So, no new li in ul is created, but the exiting changes. **The question is: how to create a new model every time I initiate addNewMovie event and render it's view (push new li to it's container)?**  I guess, I need some kind of collections.

**UPDATED (added collection)**:

```
<div id="container-addmovie"></div>
<p>Movies:</p>
<ul id="container-movie"></ul>

<!-- templates  -->
<!-- Movie template -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-movie">
    <li><strong>Title: </strong><%=title%>; <strong>Rating: </strong><%=mpaaRating%></li>
</script> 
<!-- add movie template -->
<script type="text/template" id="template-addmovie">
    <input type="text" name="" id="input-addmovie">
    <input type="button" name="" id="button-addmovie" value="Add new movie">
</script> 

<!-- models -->
<!-- movie model -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});
</script>

<!-- collections -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MovieCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Movie,
        addMovie: function(element) {
             return this.add(element);
        }
    });
</script>

<!-- views -->
<!-- movie view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#container-movie",
        template: _.template($("#template-movie").html()),
        initialize: function() {
            // model reder
            this.render();
            // change event
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            console.log("MovieView render; Movie Title: " + this.model.get("title"));
            var htmlOutput = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(htmlOutput);
            return this;
        }
    })
</script>
<!-- add movie view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AddMovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // model reder
            this.render();
            this.collection = new MovieCollection();
        },
        render: function() {
            var template =  _.template($("#template-addmovie").html());
            this.$el.html ( template );
        },
        events: {
            "click input[type=button]": "addNewMovie"
        },
        addNewMovie: function (event) {
            var elementMovie = { title: $("#input-addmovie").val(),mpaaRating:"R"};
            this.movieModel = new Movie(elementMovie);
            console.log (elementMovie);
            this.collection.addMovie(this.movieModel);
        }
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var addMovie = new AddMovieView( {el: $("#container-addmovie")} )        
</script>
```

and I still get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.collection.addMovie')`

Thanks, and sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need the collection element.
You can do something like this:

this is the collection:

```
var MovieCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Movie,
        addMovie: function(elements, options) {
             return this.add(elements, options);
        }
    });
```

inside your view for example in initialize you can do this:

```
this.collection = new MovieCollection();
```

and to add a new model Movie try this:

```
var elementMovie = { title: $("#input-addmovie").val(),mpaaRating:"R"};
this.movieModel = new Movie(element);
this.collection.addElement(this.movieModel);
```

**UPDATE**

You dont' have to create a new view, try to insert event and added method to the view of Movie, something like this:

```
var MovieView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#container-movie",
        template: _.template($("#template-movie").html()),
        initialize: function() {
            // model reder
            this.collection = new MovieCollection();
            this.render();
            // change event
            this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
        },
        render: function() {
            console.log("MovieView render; Movie Title: " + this.model.get("title"));
            var htmlOutput = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(htmlOutput);
            return this;
        },
        events: {
            "click input[type=button]": "addNewMovie"
        },
        addNewMovie: function (event) {
            var elementMovie = { title: $("#input-addmovie").val(),mpaaRating:"R"};
            this.movieModel = new Movie(elementMovie);
            console.log (elementMovie);
            this.collection.addMovie(this.movieModel);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Could you be more specific: where exactly should I create new collection with `this.collection = new MovieCollection();`? In `MovieView` initialize or in `AddMovieView`? Now I get `ypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.collection.addElement')`. Thanks for your reply

Comment: BTW, I do suppose you meant `elementMovie` in the second line, and `addMovie ` on the third, yeah? Anyway, I still get an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.collection.addMovie')`. And is it OK we create a new collection with every new view instance initialize?